# Non-generic Mvx.Resolve() method?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, mvvmcross

In my `MvvmCross` based application,
I am registering a few singleton service classes to `Mvx IOC container` inside my `Shared Core App` class, as follows:

```
CreatableTypes()
    .EndingWith("Service")
    .AsInterfaces()
    .RegisterAsSingleton();
```

All registered services inherit from a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    public abstract void MyMethod();
}
```

After App start, I would like to run `MyMethod()` on each of the registered services.

I was trying to perform the following:

```
var serviceTypes = ReflectionUtils.GetTypesFromBase<BaseService>();
foreach (Type serviceType in serviceTypes)
{
    BaseService service = (BaseService)Mvx.IocConstruct(serviceType);
    service.MyMethod();
}
```

But calling `Mvx.IocConstruct` creates another object, and I would like to perform the action on the singleton instance that was created during IoC registration.

I think that what I need is something like `Mvx.Resolve(Type t)`, but that method does not exist.

Must I specifically resolve all services and call the method on each one of the, 
or is there any alternative?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying IoC provider interface does have a method:

```
 object Resolve(Type t)
```

but it's not surfaced to the static class - no-one has ever needed it before

If you want to access it then you can - just access the ioc provider in the same way as the static `Mvx` helper does:

```
        var ioc = MvxSingleton<IMvxIoCProvider>.Instance;
        var yourObject = ioc.Resolve(type);
```

If you think it would be useful to others, please log this as a feature request for exposing via `Mvx` too.

---

Alternatively, you could call the MyMethod code yourself using Linq... something like:

```
  var query = CreatableTypes()
      .EndingWith("Service")
      .AsInterfaces();

  var serviceList = new List<BaseService>();

  foreach (var item in query)
  {
       var service = (BaseService)Mvx.IocConstruct(item.ImplementationType);
       serviceList.Add(service);
       foreach (var interfaceType in item.ServiceTypes)
       {
           Mvx.RegisterSingleton(interfaceType, service);
       }
  }

  foreach (var service in serviceList)
  {
       service.MyMethod();
  }
```

---

There is one other method which may be of use to you.

You can register callbacks for when a type is registered - see `Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered` - this will give you a callback when a type is registered (which may not be when the type is actually created).

Comment: A complete and detailed answer, as always... Thank you for your efforts!